# Use variable as selector in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click, I want to get the name of the closest div and then look for all div's, that have this name attribute and add a class to them.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container" name="button1">
    <div class="button">this is p #1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div name="button1">
  somewhere else
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.wrapper').on("click", '.button', function() {
   var attrname = $(this).closest('.container').attr('name');
   $("div[name=attrname]").each(function() {
     $(this).addClass("classtobeadded");
   });
});
```

But it is not working. So, how can I use the variable in here:

```
$("div[name=attrname]").each(function()
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4268vznu/1/):

Comment: there is no `attr` name in `.container` because There is no name attribute for div elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few issues with your logic. Firstly the `.container` element does not have the `name` attribute, the `.button` does, so you don't need to use `closest()`. Secondly, you need to concatenate the actual name value in to the selector. Lastly `div` elements do not have a `name` attribute so the HTML is invalid. If you want to store custom meta-data on an element use a `data` attribute instead.

Also note that you don't need the `each()` loop, you can just call `addClass()` on the collection selected with the `data-name` attribute. Try this:

```js
$('.wrapper').on("click", '.button', function() {
  var attrname = $(this).data('name');
  $('div[data-name="' + attrname + '"]').addClass("classtobeadded");
});
```

```css
.classtobeadded {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="button" data-name="button1">this is p #1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-name="button1">
  somewhere else
</div>
```

Comment: Can't see why you got the downvote. Sometimes I really wish we could see who it was.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen You could check for -1 in rep of people you suspect.

Comment: @nickzoum I don't think you can see the rep history of other users, can you?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `Activity`>`Reputation`, It should be `-1 downvoted`

Comment: Oh yeah, I never knew you could do that :) Thanks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Might also be worth adding `interpolation` and `Array#join` examples.

Comment: @nickzoum I agree but I got here after Rory was downvoted, so I have no clue about who it was, Honestly I would suggest that SO would add that you have to leave an anonymous comment with the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You have to concatenate it properly,

```
$(`div[name=${attrname}]`).each(function() {
```

And by the way, when looking at your code there is no attribute available in the closest div with a class `.container`. Check that as well.

Comment: update your answer because There is no name attribute for div elements.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I mentioned that in the answer. And now user has updated his question with a name `attribute` in his `div`. Thanks for letting me know that.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div[name=" + attrname + "]").each(function() {})
```

or

```
$(`div[name=${attrname}]`).each(function() {})
```